# Spring Tool Suite - IDE is not running in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to run my code in STS-IDE in debug mode, although it is running fine in normal mode but in debug mode I am facing this problem, please have a look :

[image]

I have already set this path to JDK,

[image]

Comment: I think that the `JRE name` should be again the `jdk..`.

Comment: I changed it to jdk, no luck !

Comment: I think there is an File Not Found Exception.Could give a code snippet of where it occurs and where it is handled

Comment: It is handled so it might work fine under normal execution

Comment: There is no place where it is breaking, its just that it is breaking for some eclipse configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your source lookup path. here is a steps to add path [Check this link](http://h22208.www2.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/sdn/sdnc2_6/5998-8475prog/content/s_sdnc-eclipse-AttachingSource.html)

Answer (score 0):

**This solved my problem:**

"window->Preferences->Java->Debug" and disable the "suspend execution of uncaught exceptions"

Answer (score 0):

workspace might be corrupted, Change the workspace.
File-> switch workspace -> other, select a new workspace.
And then import your project from the old workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Just try a maven clean install and run again - it might work